# fprintf opening the file, but not writing on it

Tags: c

My program opens the file but it doesn't write anything. Here's the structs and the code

```
typedef struct {
    int prioridade;
    int id;
    time_t data_criacao; 
    char descricao[MAX_STRING];
    int estado;
    pessoa *p;
    time_t prazo_conclusao;
    time_t data_conclusao;
} card;


typedef struct node_card {
    card *c;
    struct node_card*next;
} node_card;

typedef struct {
    node_card *header;
    int size;
} list_cards;

void save_file(list_cards *list){
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("D:\\Users\\Diogo\\Desktop\\projectkanban\\kanbanv2\\cartoes.txt", "w");

    node_card *curr = list->header;
    if(curr == NULL){
        return;
    }

    while(curr != NULL){
        fprintf(file, "%d;", list->header->c->prioridade);
        fprintf(file, "%d;", list->header->c->id);
        fprintf(file, "%d;", list->header->c->data_criacao);
        fprintf(file, "%s;", list->header->c->descricao);
        fprintf(file, "%d;", list->header->c->estado);
        fprintf(file, "%d;", list->header->c->p->id);
        fprintf(file, "%d;", list->header->c->prazo_conclusao);
        fprintf(file, "%d\n", list->header->c->data_conclusao);

        curr= curr->next;
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

The weird thing is when I printf all those variables it does work, I don't know why it doesn't write to the file (I've seen plenty of posts here, can't find anything that solves my problem). Maybe something wrong with my list structs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not testing whether the file could actually be opened, nor where the fprintf operations succeeded. You need to evaluate these function's return codes, and evaluate errno if an error occurred.

Comment: Would it be better if you can add the struct to the code so it can be reproduced?

Comment: Just curious, how do you know that your program opens the file?

Comment: "My program opens the file" is not demonstrated by this code as it lacks a `if(file == NULL){` check.

Comment: Hey. I know it is being opened, because not only does it create the file when it doesn't exist, but also, windows explorer says the last time it was modified.

Comment: I also edited the post with the structs.

Comment: Can you print the value of `curr` ?

Comment: `if(curr == NULL){
    return;
}` is curious.  It has no value expect to _not_ close the file when `curr == NULL`.  If there are multiple calls to `save_file()`, that will create problems.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It prints a memory address, as it should.

Comment: @chux *If there are multiple calls to `save_file()`, that will create problems.*  Indeed that will.  I suspect the last call to `save_file()` is with `curr == NULL`, as that will wipe out whatever is in the file.

Comment: Note that your while loop does not use 'curr' but 'list->c', so even though you traverse the list, you would only print the list head.

Comment: In fact, I'd bet *any* call to `save_file()` that returns due to the `if (curr == NULL)` test will result in an empty file, given this is Windows.  Because returning at that point never closes the file - after opening and truncating it.  Since this is Windows there's a good chance the any later `fopen()` call fails because the file is already open.  Lesson learned:  **always** check the results of any IO call.  And that includes `fclose()`, too, as that can fail if any buffered data can't be written.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few revisions to help guide you to a solution.

First, necessary includes & your structures,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_STRING (50)

typedef struct {
  int prioridade;
  int id;
  time_t data_criacao;
  char descricao[MAX_STRING];
  int estado;
  void *p; //pessoa *p; //not important to reporoduce
  time_t prazo_conclusao;
  time_t data_conclusao;
} card;

typedef struct node_card{
  card *c;
  struct node_card*next;
} node_card;

typedef struct {
  node_card* header;
  int size;
} list_cards;
```

Here are some revisions. Note that you may need to change the printf format specifiers, or cast time_t.

```
//you really should pass in the filename, so you can use the filename
//both in the fopen, and in the error message
//const char* filename = "D:\\Users\\Diogo\\Desktop\\projectkanban\\kanbanv2\\cartoes.txt";
const char* filename = "cartoes.txt"; //write to a local file

int save_file(char* fn, list_cards *list)
{
  FILE *file;
  node_card *curr;
  //check for valid list before opening file
  if( !list || !(curr = list->header) ) {
    printf("empty list pointer passed\n");
    return -1;
  }
  //file open here, and test for NULL return
  if ( ! (file = fopen(fn, "a+")) ) { //change "a+" to "w+" later
    printf("error: failed to open file %s\n",filename); //should be fprintf to stderr, or better to a logging file
    return -2;
  }
printf("called save file on %p\n",list->header); //how many times does this print?
  for( curr=list->header; (curr != NULL); curr=curr->next) {
//change the fprintf's to printf's for testing, delete later
printf("%d;", curr->c->prioridade);
printf("%d;", curr->c->id);
printf("%ld;", (long)curr->c->data_criacao);
printf("%s;", curr->c->descricao);
printf("%d;", curr->c->estado);
printf("%p;", curr->c->p /*->id*/);
printf("%ld;", (long)curr->c->prazo_conclusao);
printf("%ld\n", (long)curr->c->data_conclusao);
    //use curr, not list->header
    fprintf(file, "%d;", curr->c->prioridade);
    fprintf(file, "%d;", curr->c->id);
    fprintf(file, "%d;", curr->c->data_criacao);
    fprintf(file, "%s;", curr->c->descricao);
    fprintf(file, "%d;", curr->c->estado);
    fprintf(file, "%d;", curr->c->p->id);
    fprintf(file, "%d;", curr->c->prazo_conclusao);
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", curr->c->data_conclusao);
  }
  if( file) fclose(file); //defensive programming
  return 0; //always make returns explicit
} //pay the extra $0.02 for the newlines
```

Note that you can almost always r
eturn useful information, such as an error code.

Declare some minimal data, to make the example work,

```
card C = { 1,2,3, "hello", 5, NULL, 7, 8 };
node_card N = { &C, NULL };
list_cards L = { &N, 1 };
```

And a test main, so that we can watch it work. Write to a local file,

```
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  card C = { 1,2,3, "hello", 5, NULL, 6, 7 };
  node_card N = { &C, NULL }; //list has one element
  list_cards L = { &N, 1 };
  save_file(filename, &L);
}
```

Put the above in a file, compile and run, and then look at size. Since I used "a+", each run appends.

```
cat cartoes.txt 
1;2;3;hello;5;0x0;6;7
1;2;3;hello;5;0x0;6;7
```

Comment: The last `if(file)` is redundant as execution cannot reach that point if `file` is null, that would only serve to confuse the reader.  The `return;` is also redundant , and it is not clear what your intent was with "change a+ to w+ later".

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the extensive correction. In your correction, do you actually open the file? I've tried your exact code and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I've changed from fprintf to printf and it does print the variables on the console.

Comment: The if(file) is redundant, but defensive. Should someone later change code above the if, you might encounter an error. Yes, not necessary, but file IO is way more expensive than a simple test.

Comment: Do you see the "failed to open" error message or the "called save" message?

Comment: No errors or warnings, nothing. And I can see from Windows Explorer that the file is "modified" everytime I run my program. So basically, the file is open, but nothing is written.

Comment: I added a main, and an initialization of your structs (single element list), and it works. You might have a problem elsewhere. The above now extracts everything you provided to an independent test.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of:

```
if(curr == NULL){
    return;
```

you return without closing the file. So there is an open file handle on an empty file.  Any future calls to the function will then fail to open the file because the operating system may not allow two different write handles on the same file.

To avoid this problem you could move the above code to before you open the 
file;  or add a `fclose` call before returning.

Also, you should check the return value of `fopen` because if it fails then the `fprintf` commands cause undefined behaviour.

Technically you should also check the return value of `fclose` and perhaps abort the program if it fails.